# Listen for UDP multicast packets

Tags: windows, udp, autoit, multicast, ssdp

My AutoIt script should receive UDP multicast packets sent to [`239.255.250.250:9131`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol). But it doesn't work and I see no option to specify a [UDP multicast address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address) for [`UDPBind()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/UDPBind.htm).

`UDPBind()` in below code returns [error `10049` (invalid address)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668.aspx#WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL):

```
UDPStartup()
UDPBind("239.255.250.250", 9131)
While 1
   $msg = UDPRecv($recv, 512)
   If $msg <> "" Then
      ConsoleWrite($msg)
   EndIf
   Sleep(100)
WEnd
```

How to listen for UDP multicast packets?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289986/upnp-envelopes-from-scratch-not-really-working

Comment: Thanks @Bookeater, but that code receives response on non-multicast address. I want to really listen to multicast packets.

However, a comment there says _generally, you normally first bind to your local IP address and then add the multicast address afterwards_, but I did not find any function available to join multicast address.

Answer (score 1):

You must not bind to the multicast address. Bind is a local operation which sets the listening interface (on Windows) and port.

To receive multicast you need to:

- Bind to the IP address of the interface and port you want to receiv mutlicast on. On Windows bind to the IP address on the selected interface. On Linux bind to 0.0.0.0.
- Join the multicast group using the appropriate mechanisms.

Comment: I agree. I cannot find any API for the 2nd step, to join multicast group. I wonder if anyone has found a solution...